# Getting values from an id that is constantly changing

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-ide

I have a number of tests that verify sort order of search results. All of them work fine except for one particular search.

The problem is that for this search, each row has an auto-generated number for the ID, which changes everytime you do the search.

I can do this:

```
storeText | css=search_result_row_23668680919600 > td.normal.description | N1
```

And if I run the test right then it succeeds. However, any subsequent time it's run if tails, because that number in the row changes every time.

The HTML looks like this

```
<tr id="search_result_row_23668680919600">
 <td class="description">
   <a class="searchresultitem" href="/itemid"> Start of desription</a>
     <br>
       Rest of description
 </td>
```

How can I get that description text using the id when that id changes every time you run the search?

Comment: to clarify, I need to be able to do two things: 
1. Get values from id's that change each time the test is run: 
2. make sure I am always pulling values from successive rows (rows 1, 2, 3)

Comment: Why are you searching by id?  Search by `searchresultitem` should return all of your search results, from left to right, top to bottom.  `element.text` to get the text.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking entire id value just take the part of it which static.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("tr[id*='search_result_row_']>td[class='description']")).getText();
```

It will return the content of **td** every time. Store all those values and then sort using your logic.

Comment: What would that command be in Selenium IDE?  Also, I'm not trying to sort the rows, I want to grab the data from the first 3 rows and verify that they are sorted properly.

Answer (score 0):

You might try an xpath locator versus a css locator